# STDERR redirection without intermediate file

Tags: bash, io-redirection, error-handling, stderr

Here is a toy shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

misspelled_command

exec > run_$( date +%Y%m%d ).log 2>&1

echo "Logging"

exit
```

If I submit with `nohup bash raise_errors.sh > /dev/null 2> errors.log &` the error will be logged in errors.log as expected:

```
$  cat errors.log 
nohup: ignoring input
raise_errors.sh: line 5: misspelled_command: command not found
```

Is there any way to redirect the error to appear to the user in the terminal instead of `errors.log`? Also, why does `nohup: ignoring input` appear and how can it be avoided?

Comment: If you're just trying to create a script that will run a long time surviving your logout, but that you can still see messages from have you considered using `screen` or `tmux` or something like that?